# Clickjacking and XSS on file upload input?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, clickjacking, self-xss

I reported a self-xss on file uploader input to a bug bounty company and they said that they will only accept it if i can find a good clickjacking exploit for that input. My question is: Is it possible to make a clickjacking proof of concept on a file uploader input? This XSS trigger if i select a file named `<script>alert(1)<.pdf` as file to upload. Is it possible to make automatically load a file with a custom name inside of an iframed page file uploader input with just few clicks?

Comment: Why the close vote? Seems like a perfectly good question to me.

Comment: no, you cannot pre-populate a file input with JS. you could generate a file with that name to be downloaded, but that's still only half the battle...

Comment: @dandavis,
So the only way would be to have the victim download the file and then make it re-upload to the victim?
I asked if it was possible with js, but what about php/html?

Comment: it's not possible with anything.

Comment: Is that page vulnerable to clickjacking ?